# Using img tag in HTML but image wont show

Tags: html, image, tags

I'm using vscode for coding HTML but I have an issue.
When I want to use an img tag in HTML and use an image URL from the internet its OK but when I want to add a local image to the HTML it won't add and the image doesn't show but I can see that there is an image that hasn't been load.
I used both the Copy path and the Relative path and both don't work.
I'm going to share the code and site preview down below:
[image]
[image]
As you can see in the first image using a URL is ok but using a local image is not.

Can someone help me out with this?
cause I can't use any png format for the site.

if you need the whole page code its down below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foals</title>
    <h1>Foals</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="main page.html">Home </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Songs page.html">Songs</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="About page.html">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <img
        src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-SN5qocZtZGc5mtdW-wNfltQ-t500x500.jpg"
        width="250"
        height="250"
      />
    </section>
    <h2>Foals in a sight :</h2>
    <p id="SummeryInMain">
      Foals, stylized as FOALS, are a British rock band formed in Oxford in
      2005. The band's current line-up consists of a Greek-born lead vocalist and
      guitarist Yannis Philippakis, drummer and percussionist Jack Bevan and
      rhythm guitarist Jimmy Smith. They are currently signed to Warner Records,
      and have released ix studio albums s to date: Antidotes (2008), Total Life
      Forever (2010), Holy Fire (2013), What Went Down (2015), and Everything
      Not Saved Will Be Lost – Part 1 & 2 (2019), while their forthcoming
      the seventh album, Life Is Yours is scheduled to be released in June 2022.
      They have also released one video album, six extended plays and
      thirty-three singles. The band have toured internationally for over a
      decade, and have featured at many festivals including Glastonbury,
      Coachella, and Roskilde.They have won a number of awards, including best
      live act at the 2013 Q Awards while producers Alan Moulder and Flood were
      awarded 'UK Producer of the Year' for their work on the album Holy Fire.
      <br />
      <br />
      For more info about foals visit <a href="About page.html"> Here</a>
    </p>
    <h2>Concerts on the way in:</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Place</td>
        <td>Ticket</td>
        <td>Available on</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2022/4/30</td>
        <td>Glastonbury</td>
        <td>49&#163;</td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.gigsandtours.com/tour/foals" target="-blank">
            Gigsandtours
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h4>FOALS on social media:</h4>
    <nav>
      <!-- Spotify link -->
      <a
        href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/6FQqZYVfTNQ1pCqfkwVFEa"
        target="_blank"
      >
        <img
          src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6b3KKKOIKpFmjWkESxGgJKwgcXHkx19buzA&usqp=CAU"
          width="70"
          height="70"
      /></a>
      <!-- Youtube link -->
      <a
        href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnnumwiwZd1JWZWpiyqF0gQ"
        target="_blank"
      >
        <img src="youtube.png" />
      </a>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you are adding that image in a directory. Mention that directory in your image path. If you are not able to find the correct path, try opening that path in browser and edit the path until you see desired image. And then add that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your image tag to this:

```
<img src="../Photos/youtube.png" />
```

Here's how this works

`..` Go back from your **HTML files** Folder

`/Photos` Go to your **Photos** folder

`/youtube.png` get a file named **youtube.png**

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the image you want to be added is in the same folder as the HTML file, only in that case you can specify just the name of the image without the path. If the image is in the other folder, put it in the same with the HTML file or write a full path like C:\Users\Username\folder\image.png

Answer (score 1):

Is the location of the image correct? Include .jpg extension and also, Use alt attribute, so that you can specify an alternate text for the image.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly confirm image is in the same folder where's your html file
2. define width and height of the img
3. confirm use of right extension of image like .jpg, .png

Answer (score 0):

First Solution

1. Copy youtube.png in same folder where you have created main page.html

Second Solution

1. pass src image complete path Like "C:\Users\foldername\youtue.png"
2. you can do so by copying image as path